# asp.net mvc submit form using jquery mobile with parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile form with a single dropdownlist of locations. When I select a location from the DDL I want the form to submit to an action.

My Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedLocationID
, Model.AllLocation
, "Select your location")
```

My Jquery:

```
  $("#SelectedLocationID").on("change", function () {
        //var $id = $(this).val();
        $("form").submit();
        //$("form").submit({ "id": $id }, test);
    })
```

The issue is that the action requires a variable of "id" but the selected location variable is SelectedLocationID. How can I change that variable name dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `DropDownListFor` in this case because it is strongly typed and the name is generated based on the lambda expression you are passing as the argument.

You could change `DropDownListFor` to `DropDownList` instead, and pass in the name:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(Model.AllLocation), "Select your location");
```

And you will get the "id" in your action method.